# Is it possible to use the type of 'this' in a generic as a constraint itself?

Tags: c#, generics

Consider this made-up example...

```
public abstract class CollectionItem<TSelf> {

    protected CollectionItem(ICollection<TSelf> siblings)
        => Siblings = siblings;

    public ICollection<TSelf> Siblings { get; }
}

public class Foo : CollectionItem<Foo>{

    public Foo()
    : base(new FooCollection){}
}

public class FooCollection : ObservableCollection<Foo>{
}
```

With the above, `Foo` now has a `Siblings` property.  However, there are three problems with this.

1. I have to repeat the redundant `Foo` in the generic
2. `Siblings` itself isn't typed to the actual collection type, but rather the interface.
3. I have to actually pass in an instance of the `Siblings` collection

Solving for #2 and #3, I made this change...

```
public class CollectionItem<TSelf, TSiblings>
where TSiblings : ICollection<TSelf>, new() {

    protected CollectionItem()
        => Siblings = new TSiblings();

    public TSiblings Siblings { get; }
}
```

but I still have to pass in the seemingly redundant `Foo` as the first type parameter, like this...

```
public class Foo : CollectionItem<Foo, FooCollection>{

}
```

In Swift, you have an implicit `Self` datatype which always represents the type of the current instance, meaning if `Self` is used in a base class, it's actually a stand-in for the data type of the subclass. Think of it as an implicit generic if you will.

Having that in C# would allow me to do something like this...

```
public class CollectionItem<TSiblings>
where TSiblings : ICollection<Self>, new() { // Note it uses 'Self' here

    protected CollectionItem()
        => Siblings = new TSiblings();

    public TSiblings Siblings { get; }
}

public class Foo : CollectionItem<FooCollection>{

}

public class Laa : CollectionItem<LaaCollection>{

}
```

In the above, for instances of `Foo`, `Self` refers to `Foo`. For instances of `Laa`, `Self` refers to `Laa`.  No need to pass the redundant type parameters.

So does C# have anything similar?

Comment: Short answer: no

Comment: [Curiouser and curiouser](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2011/02/03/curiouser-and-curiouser/)

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/1808

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/11773